# How to return 302 redirect from Web service environment

Tags: c#, web-services, web, servicestack

I am in  a restful service environment and we are using ServiceStack as our service Framework. At this moment, I need to do a redirect directly from the service and as soon as I try to do it from my Get method it fails because I think my Get function looks somethinglike this:

```
  public override object OnGet(ShareDTO request)
        {               
           HttpContext.Current.Response.Redirect(@"http://www.google.com");
            return new object();
        }
```

May be because first it is trying to redirect and then it is trying to return  a value but this is just  wild guess. I am not sure if it is even possible in service environment because all the time whenever I have used Response.Redirect, it was always always a .NET aspx page and never tried in service environment.

Any thoughts?

Comment: Hi Guys, just found some code    var httpResult = new HttpResult(new object(), null, HttpStatusCode.Redirect);
            httpResult.Headers[HttpHeaders.Location] = "http://www.google.com";

            return httpResult;

Comment: but it throws some serviceStack exception...............

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The easiest way is to just return a custom `HttpResult`, e.g:

```
public object Any(Request request)
{
    return HttpResult.Redirect("http://www.google.com");
}
```

Which is equivalent to the more explicit:

```
return new HttpResult
{
    StatusCode = HttpStatusCode.Found,
    Headers =
    {
        { HttpHeaders.Location, "http://www.google.com" },
    }
};
```

Alternatively you can write directly to the Response, either in a [Request Filter](https://docs.servicestack.net/order-of-operations) or within a Service, e.g:

```
public object Any(Request request)
{
    base.Response.StatusCode = 302;
    base.Response.AddHeader(HttpHeaders.Location, "");
    base.Response.EndRequest();
    return null;
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your comments here and I am using your code as following `return new HttpResult()
            {
                StatusCode = HttpStatusCode.Created,
                Headers = {
                                 {
                                  HttpHeaders.Location, "http://www.google.com"
                                  }
                        }
            };
`

Comment: I am sorry my status code was ofcourse 302. which in this case is StatusCode.Redirect.